# Disabling ESC and Command . in an OSX Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, ikpicturetaker

I made a little cocoa app that brings up an IKPictureTaker and saves a picture to a file if you press the set button.  Currently, if you press esc or Command . the window picture taker will close.  Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to hide the close and Cancel buttons, so they can't be pressed:

```
IKPictureTaker *taker = [IKPictureTaker pictureTaker];
[taker setStyleMask:0]; //disable close button
for(NSView *aView in [[taker contentView] subviews]){
 if([aView isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]){
  NSButton *aButton = (NSButton*)aView;
  if([aButton action] ==  @selector(cancelButton:))
   [aButton setHidden:YES];
 }
}
```

Comment: The close button is disabled in my app, what I am asking about is how to prevent it from being close when someone pressed the esc key or command .

Comment: It's the cancel or close buttons that are acting on the esc/cmd-. So disabling them gives you the behavior you want.

But if you want the button visible, but without that key equivalent, then instead of doing [aButton setHidden:YES] do, [aButton setKeyEquivalent:@""]

Comment: This doesn't work any more on 10.9 Mavericks. If I'm missing something, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert yourself somewhere in the responder chain in time to catch the escape key down event, and disable it. You may have to subclass `IKPictureTaker`. The snippet below should help you ([source](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?EscapeKeyEvent)).

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
   if ([event keyCode] == 53) {
        NSLog(@"Escape has been pressed");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need to drop down to the low level, see the CGEvent API. Using it, you'd create a tap and swallow/modify specific events.